# Comparing string to empty array, get FutureWarning

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

I constructed a function where a string is compared to an array of strings like in the following example:

```
'A'==np.array(['A','B'])

array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

What I want is that boolean array, but sometimes the array I'm comparing with is empty and I get a warning. I was able to reproduce the FutureWarning when I get run the following:

```
'A'==np.array([])

/Users/fedgar01/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

Should I just ignore the warning or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well the point is, how do you compare a scalar `'A'` with an empty list? What should be the answer? It thus falls back on comparing the two operands, and thus returns only `False`, **not** an empty array...

Comment: For my function I do want it to output a `False` in this case. So it sounds like ignoring the warning is the best thing to do?

Comment: yes indeed. Then there is no problem. Although as the warning says, in the future, they probably will return an empty array `np.array([])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [16]: np.array(['A','B'])
Out[16]: 
array(['A', 'B'],
      dtype='<U1')
In [17]: 'A'==np.array(['A','B'])
Out[17]: array([ True, False], dtype=bool)

In [18]: 'A'==np.array([])
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[18]: False
```

If I specify the correct string dtype, I get the empty boolean:

```
In [19]: 'A'==np.array([],dtype='<U1')
Out[19]: array([], dtype=bool)
```

The default dtype for an empty array is float; numeric comparison runs without the warning:

```
In [20]: np.array([]).dtype
Out[20]: dtype('float64')
In [21]: 12.34==np.array([])
Out[21]: array([], dtype=bool)
```